# What is the differences between using Spark lit and not using it?

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to understand the effect of [lit](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#lit-java.lang.Object-) function in Spark. Both of the following codes do the same things

```
    import spark.sqlContext.implicits._
    import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
    import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

    val data = Seq(("111",50000),("222",60000),("333",40000))

    val df = data.toDF("EmpId","Salary") 

    val df2 = df.select(col("EmpId"),col("Salary"),lit("1").as("lit_value1"))
    

    val df3 = df2.withColumn("lit_value2", when(col("Salary") >=40000 && col("Salary") <= 50000, lit("100").cast(IntegerType)).otherwise(lit("200").cast(IntegerType)))

// same as above! 
    val df4 = df2.withColumn("lit_value2", when(col("Salary") >=40000 && col("Salary") <= 50000, 100).otherwise(200))
```

Answer (score 0):

`when` has the below signature:

```scala
def when(condition: org.apache.spark.sql.Column,value: Any): org.apache.spark.sql.Column
```

The type of `value` is `Any` and it accepts either a `Column` or a number/string/etc.

In `df3` you provided the `value` as a `Column` using `lit`, whereas in `df4` you provided the `value` as a number without using `lit`.

They are equivalent ways to provide the value argument to `when`, but `df4` is a simpler way to do so. Under the hood, I believe that Spark will convert the numerical value that you provided into a literal column, similar to what `lit` will do.